# Programmatically open Kendo Context Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, contextmenu

I'm using Kendo UI. how to open context menu programmatically?

example

```
<a href="#" onclick="openContextMenu">Menu</a>
<script>
function openContextMenu() {
//how to call to open context menu?
$("#contextMenu").data("kendoContextMenu")??? 

}
</script>
```

alternative way is using kendoPopup
http://jsfiddle.net/bundyo/3XNzE/

but i tried not use kendoPopup bcoz Kendo has released ContextMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use open function to open Kendo UI Context Menu.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/contextmenu#methods-open

See this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OCIr/5) example I made.